# XSLT Iterate convert to CSV

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xpath

Can someone help me in transforming below xml to csv(in below format).

XML>

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
      <Shop>Walmart</Shop>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ResponseEnvelope>
      <Response>
        <Part_electronics>
          <type>electronics</type>
          <item>Freeze</item>
        </Part_electronics>
        <Part_utility>
          <type>utility</type>
          <item>Parker</item>
        </Part_utility>
        <Part_grocery>
          <type>grocery</type>
          <item>sugar</item>
        </Part_grocery>
      </Response>
    </ResponseEnvelope>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**strong text**
CSV OUTPUT:

```
Walmart,electronics,Freeze
Walmart,utility,pen
Walmart,grocery,sugar
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a coding service.  Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name()= 'Shop']">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), '&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:variable name="Response" select="/*[local-name()= 'Response']"></xsl:variable>
         <xsl:for-each select="$Response/*/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), '&#10;')"></xsl:value-of>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: However above doesn't work properly and its printing each column value in a separate line. Need some guidance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the above XSLT. It is hard to read XSLT in comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want row for every "part_" element. In this case, you should start off by selecting those elements

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Response/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Part_')]">
```

Then you can get the fields, by selecting all the children

```
     <xsl:for-each select="*">
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
     </xsl:for-each>
```

This assumes all the "Part_" elements have the same number of elements in the same order.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/> 
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="Shop" select="//Shop" />
      <xsl:for-each select="//Response/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Part_')]"> 
         <xsl:value-of select="$Shop"/> 
         <xsl:for-each select="*">
             <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
             <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each> 
   </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs the following:

```
Walmart,electronics,Freeze
Walmart,utility,Parker
Walmart,grocery,sugar
```